# CMUSphinx-go PortAudio error: Device unavailable

Tags: ubuntu, go, cmusphinx, portaudio

I had installed [pocketsphinx-go](https://github.com/xlab/pocketsphinx-go) by instruction in repo. But when i runing example gortana i see error:

> ```
> Loading CMU PhocketSphinx.
> This may take a while depending on the size of your model.
> PortAudio error: Device unavailable
> exit status 1
> ```

What to do? Is there any other offline stt?
PS: System: Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 0):

Configure alsa properly, so the portaudio will detect the device.